# UserControl event

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a usercontrol, it consists of a picturebox with an image, add it to project, try to expose him to a click event, but it does not respond! What am I doing wrong?
http://www.fileserve.com/file/yk9sjAu - usercontrol
http://www.fileserve.com/file/4353g9z - my project

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.  Also, give more detail as to exactly how and where in the process it's failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The click event only fires for clicks directly on your UserControl itself - not it's children.

To pass clicks from these as well, you need to chain the events:

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.pictureBox1.Click += (s,e) => {base.OnClick(e);};
        this.checkBox1.Click += (s,e) => {base.OnClick(e);};
    }
```